# Get nulls in response from server in android

Tags: android, gson

I get response from server:

```
{"lists":[{"listId":"335","name":"Lists","offers":[{"offerId":"880","startDatetime":"2017-04-01 00:00:00","endDatetime":"2017-11-30 23:59:00","sortPriority":"0","offerName":"bursdag"}]}]}
```

this is my classes:

```
public class List {


private String listId;

private String name;

private java.util.List<Offer> offers = null;

public String getListId() {
return listId;
}

public void setListId(String listId) {
this.listId = listId;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public java.util.List<Offer> getOffers() {
return offers;
}

public void setOffers(java.util.List<Offer> offers) {
this.offers = offers;
}

}


package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Offer {

private String offerId;
private String startDatetime;
private String endDatetime;
private String sortPriority;
private String offerName;

public String getOfferId() {
return offerId;
}

public void setOfferId(String offerId) {
this.offerId = offerId;
}

public String getStartDatetime() {
return startDatetime;
}

public void setStartDatetime(String startDatetime) {
this.startDatetime = startDatetime;
}

public String getEndDatetime() {
return endDatetime;
}

public void setEndDatetime(String endDatetime) {
this.endDatetime = endDatetime;
}

public String getSortPriority() {
return sortPriority;
}

public void setSortPriority(String sortPriority) {
this.sortPriority = sortPriority;
}

public String getOfferName() {
return offerName;
}

public void setOfferName(String offerName) {
this.offerName = offerName;
}

}
```

My listId is null and all fields from offers are null.
Any ideas why?

ListResponse:

```
public class ListResponse {
    List<List> list;

    public List<List> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setApps(List<List> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your java file. How you decode the response.

Comment: Your class `ListResponse` has field named `list` instead of `lists` that is in your json, is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use like this for using gson in all other variable

```
@SerializedName("listId")
  private String listId;
```